# "Segue through" vs "Segue into"

Tags: word-usage

Does this sentence make sense?

```
An experienced writing coach can help you segue through the writing process
```

I usually think of segue as "segue into" or as a noun, but this is "segue through." The sentence was written by the writing coach being advertised, so she should know what she's talking about with regards to writing. Is it some usage that I've never heard of?

Comment: I think you maybe misunderstand the modern figurative extension of ***segue** (originally **music:** to move without interruption from one song or melody to another)* which is now used in the more general sense of *seamlessly move from one **topic** [of conversation] to another*. Or your source did, in which case maybe it's not the best example of an "experienced writing coach".

Comment: It sounds strange to me. 'through' has the metaphorical sense of already being inside a thing, but 'segue' is metaphorically a transition from one place to a next. So 'segue into' is natural, whereas 'segue through' seems a mismatch.

Answer (score 1):

Since *segue* means to move from one thing to another seamlessly, (literally from one piece of music to another, but figuratively used of other things) I imagine they intend this to mean that you both move into and then out of the writing process with ease.

If so, it's a poor use; *segue* refers to the way in which the transition from one thing to the next is seemless as observed by another. This doesn't really make much sense in terms of the writing process. (Except perhaps for those days in which the transition from doing things like answering questions on EL&U to getting some writing done was indeed seemless, because one never actually got any writing done).

I think they are perhaps thinking of the more general idea of "ease" and applying *segue* to that, but that seems far too much a stretch to be felicitous.

Comment: In fairness, I'd hate to try to write about how I could make writing easy for someone; what pressure it applies to a piece of text that is at the same time banal. It's much nicer to be able to just talk about good writing as an ideal as I tend to do in answers here, rather than claiming that I can achieve it by any objective measure.

Comment: That's what I thought. I just wanted confirmation before arguing with "an experienced writing coach" :)

Comment: Well, if they aren't already adamant, then just asking "are you sure about segue here?" might be fine; that we all need to consider that we may have overstretched a sense is one of the things a writing coach teaches, after all.